# gapro.idstring=||title|| in the Google Analytics Pro Plugin

Tags: google-analytics, jwplayer

I've recently added both the JWPlayer and the GAPro addon to my site.

The tracking seemed to be working until I added the custom flashvar:

gapro.idstring=||title||

I'm not getting any event data in GA now (I am however getting visitor data to that page)

Reading their forums, I'm guessing it's because there isn't a "title" value for it to pull from. Looking at my page source code, all I see that references the video title is:

meta property='og:title' content='Taiwan Artist Shara Lin'

How do I fix this? Is the right way to do something like:

gapro.idstring=||og:title||

or do i have to manually add it to my shortcode like:

[jwplayer config="Conversioneering" title="Taiwan Artist Shara Lin" mediaid="337"]

your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve the issue by adding the title to the shortcode

```
[jwplayer config="storybridge" title="Nothing Simply title" mediaid="337"]
```

If you can have multiple videos on one page, each with their own title,  GA will capture all of the video tracking info per video.